# Compiling a program on a server

Tags: mysql, c, makefile

I'm new to servers and programming in general, and I have a question regarding remote acces to a server, and how much I can actually do on it.

The thin is I have a working program on a linux server, which I acces with my windows machine using mobaxterm. I can acces the server, I see folders and a cmd line, where I can compile a makefile. Everything runs well, however when I run the makefile it just compiles, and doesn't do anything. No error messages, but also no opening of a program. I don't understand anything. Is it a delimitation of the servers structure, that it can only store files on it?

Comment: Compiling source code is different to executing a program.

Comment: True, it doesn't spit out an .exe file

Comment: It supose to open up an interactive map, with colors and everything, is this even possible on a server? Doesn't that require a lot of other programs...

Comment: What's wrong if the makefile only compiles? It has probably been written to do exactly this. If there are no compile errors or warnings the invocation of make may very well show nothing.

Comment: You misunderstand. When you execute Make, and it runs a makefile, it may or may not execute another program, depending on what the makefile says. This is not a problem of the file system, or the server architecture, or anything else.

Comment: Are you supposed to get the coloured interactive map through the console (MobaXTerm), or after, like through a browser or some such?

Comment: That's the thing I don't know. The program is available online, but I have to alter it to some other database, and have to do this through the mobaxterm I think

Comment: @1233023: If your mobaxterm is [this one](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html), then it does support X11 forwarding, and has a built-in X server. This means that yes, you can run graphical programs on a (Linux) server, with the windows actually appearing on your Windows machine. (The server machine needs to have X libraries installed, but does not need an X server to run; that'll run on your Windows machine only.) You do need a pretty low-latency high-bandwidth connection for it to feel smooth, though; otherwise, expect the initial window opening and most actions to take a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

When you compile under linux using a make, it produces an executable but does not run it. Make builds executable objects, but it does not run them. You should include your makefile in the question (reduced to a minimum if it is large). Inside it, you will see that it generates a executable file with a specific name. To run it, you need to invoke this from the command line.

To find out what it is building, a quick way is to type "make clean" (press enter of course) to clean up any built objects. Then type the "ls" command to see what is in your directory.

Next, build the program with the "make" command, then type "ls" to see what has been added. Ignore any new files that end in .o or .a or .so and look for any new files. These are the files built by make and at least one of them is the program you built.

Assuming you found a new file called "myprogram". To run it, type:

```
./myprogram
```

Comment: Thanks for being explicit! I'll try to look at the makefile.

Comment: @1233023: You can also run `find . -type f -perm -u=x ls` to list all executable files in current directory and subdirectories. Running it before and after `make` is often an easy way to find the built binaries. (Or, if you only run it after `make`, check the date and time in the listing; if it was just built, the file date should reflect it.)